# Changing a column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R with a column with values as "s1-112", "s10-112", "s3656-112" etc. Now i want to change the values to only the part after "s" and before "-112" that is the number after s. is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `gsub` here

```
x<-c("s1-112", "s10-112", "s3656-112")
gsub("s(.*)-112", "\\1", x)
# [1] "1"    "10"   "3656"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or (using @MrFlick's data)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, perl('\\d+(?=-)'))
#[1] "1"    "10"   "3656"
```